# Integrate $\frac{3}{\sqrt{-5x^2-4\sqrt{5}x+2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Integrate $\frac{3}{\sqrt{-5x^2-4\sqrt{5}x+2}}$

For this question I first factored out the 3, seeing as its a constant

$$3\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{-5x^2-4\sqrt{5}x+2}}dx$$

I then noticed that this integral has a similar form to the integral of $\arcsin(x)$

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx=\arcsin(\frac{x}{a})+C,   \vert x \vert \lt a$$

The similarities between these two integrals is clear, but I dont know how to get from $$-5x^2-4\sqrt{5}x+2$$ to $$a^2-x^2$$

Any help or ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: $$ -5x^2-4\sqrt{5}x\color{red}{-4}\color{red}{+4}+2 = 6-\left(5x^2+4\sqrt{5}x+4\right) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather messy completing the square:

$-5x^2-4\sqrt{5}x+2$

$-5\left(x^2+\frac{4\sqrt{5}x}{5}\right)+2$

$2-5\left(x+\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5} \right)^2+4$

$(\sqrt{6})^2-\left(\sqrt{5}\left(x+\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5} \right)\right)^2$

Comment: that is an incredibly messy completing teh square, youre right. any "easier" methods? or is this the only one?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write 
$$-5x^2-4\sqrt{5}x+2=6-(\sqrt{5}x+2)^2$$
and let substitution $\sqrt{5}x+2=\sqrt{6}\sin\theta$.